# Setting #define identifier using command line argument

Tags: c++, c++11, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a python script to run a compiled binary whose source was written in C++, varying a parameter as controlled using a command line argument.

e.g. `os.system("./my_program " + my_arg)`

Let's say it's too much hassle changing this parameter from `main()`.

Instead I'd like to set it in some included header file using
`#define MY_PARAM my_val`
where `my_val` is taken as a command line argument when the program is run.

I'm using gcc to compile

Any ideas?

Comment: Your application would have to know to read your config file. Do you have something like this in your application already?

Comment: "python script to run a c++ program" do you mean compiled binary which source was written on C++? Or this script will take the source C++, compile it and then execute it?

Comment: Are you targeting a specific OS?

Comment: What compiler are you using? For example, if using `gcc`, the `-D name=definition` arguments could be used to `#define` a macro with a specific value from the shell.

Comment: Have made edits for clarification

Comment: I think you should explain what you mean by "changing this parameter from `main()`" and what the "hassle" is. It sounds like you mean the command line parameter, which is `argv[1]` and causes very little hassle.

Comment: @user1488804 You cannot do this. `#define` doesn't exist in the binary. It only exists in the source code. If you are using the binary executable, the value is already there. You can only program it to be updated through the program input params or the environment variables (which has alsomst identical complexity).

Comment: @user1488804: Please don't forget to accept an answer if it turned out to be useful for you and ask clarifying questions if something's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb question. I guess I didn't properly understand the problem I was trying to solve before asking! I got past this problem by:

1. Adding optional arguments in the makefile using the -D option to set these compile-time variables. This replaces specified variable names with the values given when running `make`.
2. A python script looped through a bunch of options, each time calling `os.system("make OPT1=" + str(opt1) + "OPT2=" + str(opt2))` etc. followed by os.system("./myprog | tee mylogfile.log")
3. The python script then parsed the logfile, which contained output that varied as a function of the options inputted as arguments to `make`.

Hope this helps anyone wanting to do something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code snippet:

```
os.system("./my_program " + my_arg)
```

You're just trying to send an argument input to your program. You don't need to use preprocessor definitions (e.g. `#define SOMETHING`) for it. (In fact, you can't, because the binary has already been built.)

Instead, you modify your `main` function from `int main()` to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

You'd use it in a way similar to what's below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        std::cout << "Argument " << i << ": " << argv[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Sample runs from the code above, which was placed in the `test.cpp` file and used from the Python3 interactive interpreter:

```
➜  /tmp  g++ test.cpp -o argtest
➜  /tmp  ./argtest
Argument 0: ./argtest
➜  /tmp  ./argtest a b c d e 123
Argument 0: ./argtest
Argument 1: a
Argument 2: b
Argument 3: c
Argument 4: d
Argument 5: e
Argument 6: 123
➜  /tmp  python3
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50)
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from os import system
>>> system('./argtest a b c 123')
Argument 0: ./argtest
Argument 1: a
Argument 2: b
Argument 3: c
Argument 4: 123
0
>>>
```

The zero at the end is the return code from Python's `system` call saying everything went fine.