# How to pass a file to an .exe in console

Tags: c, file, console

i am currently learning C by reading "The C proggraming Language".
I have issues with exercices that implies input and output with `getchar()`/`putchar()`/`EOF`. It seems that the programs made with the exercises are supposed to be used on files. But once i have my `.exe` i only know how to start the "raw" .exe, i would like to do something like: `myProgram.exe file.txt`
This way the program could read the file as input. Unfortunatly the way i try to do this doesn't work, could you tell me how to do this properly?

Program i want to use on a file 
(**this is code from the book**, there is no int main() or anything else):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
         putchar(c);
    }
}
```

I am on Windows 8.1, using cl ( visual studio compiler), version 19 x64.

Comment: Very similar to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476708/setting-define-identifier-using-command-line-argument/33476949#33476949](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476708/setting-define-identifier-using-command-line-argument/33476949#33476949).

Comment: `int main(void)` is strictly-conforming.

Comment: What operating system are you running your program on? Here are the 2nd editon book solutions created by the authors : K&R2 solutions- http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions

Comment: @SoftwareCarpenter I already checked this site, it's awesome but they don't mention how to execute program with a file parameter. ( I edited my question to add stuff like OS, compiler...)

Comment: @user3121023 That's it, this is exactly what i was looking for, i dont know why this is not mentionned in the book :/ . Thanks!

Comment: While redirection is very useful, it is really part of the operating system (not C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the commandline arguments

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//argc = number of arguments on command line

//argv[] = the file names on the command line. Note* the exe will always be argv[0]
}
```

In your program you can refer to argv[1] as your text file that you pass in.

```
./a.out myTextFile.txt
```

here argc = 2 and argv[0] = a.out while argv[1] = myTextFile.txt

I suggest you look into modifying your code to include this, during file reading.

Comment: @Samer: The same `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` applies to Windows. This is standard C++

Comment: @scerr ./a.out myTextFile.txt... is not windows!

Comment: a.out is self explanatory as an executable.

Comment: In fact i had heard of this main() signature and i suspected it to be use for something among those lines. But the book is dedicated to C begginers so i am trying to resolves exercices whith information met in the book only. Thanks still.

Comment: @aurelienC: If you're trying to limit yourself only to the information provided in the book, then why ask here? The point is that the modified signature for `main` is what allows your program to receive the arguments the caller has sent through the command-line, regardless of whether you're on Windows or GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows OS and cl then do the following.
Also, refer to the c standard regarding main [C Standard - 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.1.html)

**1.** Overload your main function to accept command line arguments.

**2.** Compile your program from the command line using cl.exe :

```
cl simple.c
```

**3.** Call the compiled .exe from the command line

```
simple "filepath\filename"
```

**See MSDN Walkthrough**: [Compiling a C Program on the Command Line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define LINES_PER_PAGE 10
#define TRUE           1
#define FALSE          0


void print_file(char* file_name)
{
    FILE* f;
    int page_number = 1;
    int line_count;
    int c;
    int new_page = TRUE;

    assert(file_name != NULL);
    FILE** f2;
    if ((f = fopen(file_name, "r")) != NULL)
    {
        while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
        {
            if (new_page)
            {
                /* print out the header */
                printf("[%s] page %d starts\n", file_name, page_number);
                new_page = FALSE;
                line_count = 1;
            }
            putchar(c);
            if (c == '\n' && ++line_count > LINES_PER_PAGE)
            {
                /* print out the footer */
                printf("[%s] page %d ends\n", file_name, page_number);
                /* skip another line so we can see it on screen */
                putchar('\n');
                new_page = TRUE;
                page_number++;
            }
        }
        if (!new_page)
        {
            /* file ended in the middle of a page, so we still need to
            print a footer */
            printf("[%s] page %d ends\n", file_name, page_number);
        }
        /* skip another line so we can see it on screen */
        putchar('\n');
        fclose(f);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int i;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fputs("no files specified\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {

        print_file(argv[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```